# Copy/Paste from Excel to a WebApp

Tags: excel, web, copy, paste

I have to create a Web app which can allowed to copy from excel and paste on the web and get exacly the same thing and vice versa.
I don't know many things on web development but I found some solution like :

-sharepoint and office web app

-asp.net + ajax

-make a add-in in excel to send elem on a server (but the project will be only on excel 
with this solution)

-HTML + PHP with PHPExcel.

Are there others solutions or which one of these is the best?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

a client side solution 
have a look handsontable jquery plugin. u can use copy/paste from excel
http://handsontable.com/
if you want to do it in server side just two for statement parse all. lots of class available for parsing.

Comment: But the office web app is more powerful isn't it?
And my compagny like Windows tools so I might make a excel web app so can anyone tell me the advantages/disadvantages of this?

Answer (score 0):

i use spreadsheetgear core in my .net refrence and use of many capabilities of:

http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/

it seems perfect!